# Hibernate дублирует запрос

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, запрос

При выполнении `count` запроса `Hibernate` почему-то дублирует его. Это не похоже на проблему N+1, ведь он не выбирает никаких дочерних сущностей, а просто повторяет один и тот же запрос один-в-один. Почему и как это исправить?

**Вот часть стэктрейса:**

```
Hibernate: select ct1_0.author_id,ct1_0.id,ct1_0.created_at,ct1_0.description,ct1_0.edited_at,e1_0.id,e1_0.email,e1_0.name,e1_0.password,e1_0.registration_date,ct1_0.priority,ct1_0.status,ct1_0.title from tasks ct1_0 left join people e1_0 on e1_0.id=ct1_0.executor_id where ct1_0.author_id=?
0
2024-03-25T02:31:44.491+03:00 DEBUG 21948 --- [TaskManager] [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
1
2024-03-25T02:31:44.493+03:00 DEBUG 21948 --- [TaskManager] [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
2
2024-03-25T02:31:44.495+03:00 DEBUG 21948 --- [TaskManager] [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(c1_0.id) 
    from
        comments c1_0 
    left join
        tasks t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
3
```

**Цикл в методе контроллера, где происходит дублирование:**

```
            int i = 0;
            for (JsonNode node : tasksNode) { 
                System.out.println(i++);
                int commentsCount = commentService.countByTask(node.get("id").asInt()); // В этой строке происходит дублирование запроса            
                ((ObjectNode)node).set("comments", objectMapper.convertValue(commentsCount + " comments, " 
                + (int) (Math.ceil((double) commentsCount / PAGE_SIZE)) + " pages", JsonNode.class)); // *
            }
```

Я пробовал закомментировать строку, помеченную звездочкой - это не решило проблему.

**В сервисе:**

```
    public Integer countByTask(long id) {
        return commentRepository.countByTask_id(id);
    }
```

**В репозитории:**

```
Integer countByTask_id(long id);
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.terentyev</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TaskManager</name>
    <description>Web + REST Task Manager</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
             <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
             <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: а точно дублирует? Текст может быть один, но если аргументы (id в данном случае) разные - это будут разные запросы. Да и не видно, чтобы была аннотация кеширования или транзакция, т.е. даже при одинаковых аргументах результат выполнения может быть разным, если кто-то другой изменит содержимое БД

Comment: @kami Результат сохранения может быть совсем не идентичный если пользователи меняют его одновременно. Всем пользователям надо ставить транзакцию чтобы они не вытаскивали чужие объекты. Если запросы идентичные, что собственно надо ещё проверить значения параметров, то за такое короткое время не может быть сделано несколько запросов. Точное количество запросов можно определить из сессии пользователя. Системными утилитами делать запросы в бд, зная ID сессии, осматривать запросы пользователя.

Comment: @RomanC к чему была адресация меня? Не вижу противоречия с моим комментарием. Единственное, с чем не согласен - "всем ставить транзакцию". В некоторых случаях явно стартуемая транзакция может быть излишней, вполне хватит неявной. Ну разве что используется "грязное чтение", но тогда и транзакция не поможет.

Comment: @kami Потому, что ты оставил здесь свой комент. Не совсем понятно что ты имеешь ввиду, явная транзакция или неявная, причем последняя требует пояснения. Это к тому, почему метод репозитория не работает если убрать у него `@Transactional`. А то получается что тут целая куча определений транзакций и ни одна из них не является верной. "Грязное чтение" - это ты уже залез в определения уровней изоляции, ну какие ещё есть уровни? Надо было спросить о этом у вопросчика, какое чтение у него используется программой и как оно может помочь решить проблему. Над этим стоит поразмыслить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Транзакции включены. Никакое кеширование, во всяком случае сам, не включал - все по умолчанию.
Ну приложение учебное, других пользователей у него нет.

Comment: Думаю мало кому приятно рыться в горе кода, поэтому выложил минимум.

Comment: @RomanC опять не увидел расшифровки - в чем противоречие относительно моего первого комментария? Применительно к транзакциям - что нужно пояснить про implicit transaction?  По поводу "всем пользователям ставить транзакцию" - повторю, это излишне. Если выполняется только один SELECT (а в вопросе именно так), то явная транзакция не нужна. Дальше уже даже комментировать не хочется - никаких верных или не верных определений транзакциям не давалось, про `@Transactional` над методами тоже речь не шла... Ощущение, что ваш комментарий частично относится к какому-то другому обсуждению.

Comment: @kami Не увидел - это твои проблемы. Относительно транзакций проясни, что ты имел ввиду "если кто-то другой изменит содержимое БД". Разный результат, хотя судя по описанию вопроса такого не наблюдается. Наоборот запросы абсолютно идентичные, если я правильно понял вопрос. И я вообще не понял, с чего ты взял, что аргументы могут быть разные? Понятно, что на твои вопросы ты не получил ответ. В рамках транзакции невозможно выполнить запросы от нескольких пользователей, поэтому результат выполнения запросов будет абсолютно идентичный. Но тут в начал спорить по поводу транзакций и уткнулся.

Comment: @RomanC `Не увидел - это твои проблемы`. Понятно. Хорошая позиция: "свои высказывания пояснять я не буду, а оппонент пусть аргументирует". Спасибо за непродуктивную беседу.